# Why does this cause Mac OSX to print over SSH?

Tags: macos, bash, command-line, ssh, script

While screwing around and breaking things I came across these stupid commands (if executed in order it causes what I got):

`cd / && cat vmlinuz`

`cd /boot/ && cat init*`

It causes special characters that aren't recognized by the system like `���` however, for some reason it causes weird effects like causing iTerm2 to send a bell (a notification to the system) like the screen shot:

[image]

However, the weirdest this is that is causes Mac OSX to print (screenshot):

[image]

Can someone explain to my why this happens, especially over SSH?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminal.app probably implements the "media copy" (printer) escape sequence from VT100s.  You can read about those control sequences at [vt100.net](http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt102-ug/chapter5.html), or in the [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html), e.g.,

```
CSI Pm i  Media Copy (MC).
        Ps = 0  -> Print screen (default).
        Ps = 4  -> Turn off printer controller mode.
        Ps = 5  -> Turn on printer controller mode.
CSI ? Pm i
      Media Copy (MC, DEC-specific).
        Ps = 1  -> Print line containing cursor.
        Ps = 4  -> Turn off autoprint mode.
        Ps = 5  -> Turn on autoprint mode.
        Ps = 1  0  -> Print composed display, ignores DECPEX.
        Ps = 1  1  -> Print all pages.
```